# Got error " Voucher totals do not match!" in tally import with node js

Tags: node.js, tally

I am trying to import xlsx file to tally. I have converted xlsx to XML in node js. I am trying to upload my converted XML to tally with node js. following is my XML code.

```
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
   <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
   <IMPORTDATA>
    <REQUESTDESC>
     <REPORTNAME>Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
     <STATICVARIABLES>
      <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>xyz abc</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
     </STATICVARIABLES>
    </REQUESTDESC>
    <REQUESTDATA>
     <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
      <VOUCHER REMOTEID="cfa688b5-2b1f-430f-a0f1-2e32fad3187e" VCHKEY="94eebd66-d8bc-42a4-a58e-96d09c3b0702-0000acfe:00000098" VCHTYPE="abc Sales Test" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Invoice Voucher View">
       <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
        <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
       </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
       <DATE>20211031</DATE>
       <REFERENCEDATE>20211031</REFERENCEDATE>
       <GUID>cfa688b5-2b1f-430f-a0f1-2e32fad3187e</GUID>
       <GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>Consumer</GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>
       <STATENAME>Maharashtra</STATENAME>
       <NARRATION>INVOICE NO 64UVR0000000000 DATE 1-Apr-21 ORDER ID OD121335849112614000</NARRATION>
       <COUNTRYOFRESIDENCE>India</COUNTRYOFRESIDENCE>
       <PLACEOFSUPPLY>Maharashtra</PLACEOFSUPPLY>
       <PARTYNAME>Maharashtra</PARTYNAME>
       <PARTYLEDGERNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
       <VOUCHERTYPENAME>abc Sales Test</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
       <REFERENCE>OD223255075455441000</REFERENCE>
       <PARTYMAILINGNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</PARTYMAILINGNAME>
       <CONSIGNEEGSTIN>08AEHPB1234R000</CONSIGNEEGSTIN>
       <CONSIGNEEMAILINGNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</CONSIGNEEMAILINGNAME>
       <CONSIGNEESTATENAME>Maharashtra</CONSIGNEESTATENAME>
       <VOUCHERNUMBER>FAkmJX2200005080</VOUCHERNUMBER>
       <BASICBASEPARTYNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
       <CSTFORMISSUETYPE/>
       <CSTFORMRECVTYPE/>
       <FBTPAYMENTTYPE>Default</FBTPAYMENTTYPE>
       <PERSISTEDVIEW>Invoice Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
       <BASICBUYERNAME>xyz Internet Pvt. Ltd</BASICBUYERNAME>
       <BASICFINALDESTINATION>Maharashtra</BASICFINALDESTINATION>
       <CONSIGNEECOUNTRYNAME>India</CONSIGNEECOUNTRYNAME>
       <VCHGSTCLASS/>
       <VCHENTRYMODE>Item Invoice</VCHENTRYMODE>
       <ENTEREDBY>v</ENTEREDBY>
       <DIFFACTUALQTY>No</DIFFACTUALQTY>
       <ISMSTFROMSYNC>No</ISMSTFROMSYNC>
       <ASORIGINAL>No</ASORIGINAL>
       <AUDITED>No</AUDITED>
       <FORJOBCOSTING>No</FORJOBCOSTING>
       <ISOPTIONAL>No</ISOPTIONAL>
       <EFFECTIVEDATE>20211031</EFFECTIVEDATE>
       <USEFOREXCISE>No</USEFOREXCISE>
       <ISFORJOBWORKIN>No</ISFORJOBWORKIN>
       <ALLOWCONSUMPTION>No</ALLOWCONSUMPTION>
       <USEFORINTEREST>No</USEFORINTEREST>
       <USEFORGAINLOSS>No</USEFORGAINLOSS>
       <USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>No</USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>
       <USEFORCOMPOUND>No</USEFORCOMPOUND>
       <USEFORSERVICETAX>No</USEFORSERVICETAX>
       <ISDELETED>No</ISDELETED>
       <ISONHOLD>No</ISONHOLD>
       <ISBOENOTAPPLICABLE>No</ISBOENOTAPPLICABLE>
       <ISGSTSECSEVENAPPLICABLE>No</ISGSTSECSEVENAPPLICABLE>
       <ISEXCISEVOUCHER>No</ISEXCISEVOUCHER>
       <EXCISETAXOVERRIDE>No</EXCISETAXOVERRIDE>
       <USEFORTAXUNITTRANSFER>No</USEFORTAXUNITTRANSFER>
       <IGNOREPOSVALIDATION>No</IGNOREPOSVALIDATION>
       <EXCISEOPENING>No</EXCISEOPENING>
       <USEFORFINALPRODUCTION>No</USEFORFINALPRODUCTION>
       <ISTDSOVERRIDDEN>No</ISTDSOVERRIDDEN>
       <ISTCSOVERRIDDEN>No</ISTCSOVERRIDDEN>
       <ISTDSTCSCASHVCH>No</ISTDSTCSCASHVCH>
       <INCLUDEADVPYMTVCH>No</INCLUDEADVPYMTVCH>
       <ISSUBWORKSCONTRACT>No</ISSUBWORKSCONTRACT>
       <ISVATOVERRIDDEN>No</ISVATOVERRIDDEN>
       <IGNOREORIGVCHDATE>No</IGNOREORIGVCHDATE>
       <ISVATPAIDATCUSTOMS>No</ISVATPAIDATCUSTOMS>
       <ISDECLAREDTOCUSTOMS>No</ISDECLAREDTOCUSTOMS>
       <ISSERVICETAXOVERRIDDEN>No</ISSERVICETAXOVERRIDDEN>
       <ISISDVOUCHER>No</ISISDVOUCHER>
       <ISEXCISEOVERRIDDEN>No</ISEXCISEOVERRIDDEN>
       <ISEXCISESUPPLYVCH>No</ISEXCISESUPPLYVCH>
       <ISGSTOVERRIDDEN>No</ISGSTOVERRIDDEN>
       <GSTNOTEXPORTED>No</GSTNOTEXPORTED>
       <IGNOREGSTINVALIDATION>No</IGNOREGSTINVALIDATION>
       <ISGSTREFUND>No</ISGSTREFUND>
       <OVRDNEWAYBILLAPPLICABILITY>No</OVRDNEWAYBILLAPPLICABILITY>
       <ISVATPRINCIPALACCOUNT>No</ISVATPRINCIPALACCOUNT>
       <IGNOREEINVVALIDATION>No</IGNOREEINVVALIDATION>
       <IRNJSONEXPORTED>No</IRNJSONEXPORTED>
       <IRNCANCELLED>No</IRNCANCELLED>
       <ISSHIPPINGWITHINSTATE>No</ISSHIPPINGWITHINSTATE>
       <ISOVERSEASTOURISTTRANS>No</ISOVERSEASTOURISTTRANS>
       <ISDESIGNATEDZONEPARTY>No</ISDESIGNATEDZONEPARTY>
       <ISCANCELLED>No</ISCANCELLED>
       <HASCASHFLOW>No</HASCASHFLOW>
       <ISPOSTDATED>No</ISPOSTDATED>
       <USETRACKINGNUMBER>No</USETRACKINGNUMBER>
       <ISINVOICE>Yes</ISINVOICE>
       <MFGJOURNAL>No</MFGJOURNAL>
       <HASDISCOUNTS>No</HASDISCOUNTS>
       <ASPAYSLIP>No</ASPAYSLIP>
       <ISCOSTCENTRE>No</ISCOSTCENTRE>
       <ISSTXNONREALIZEDVCH>No</ISSTXNONREALIZEDVCH>
       <ISEXCISEMANUFACTURERON>No</ISEXCISEMANUFACTURERON>
       <ISBLANKCHEQUE>No</ISBLANKCHEQUE>
       <ISVOID>No</ISVOID>
       <ORDERLINESTATUS>No</ORDERLINESTATUS>
       <VATISAGNSTCANCSALES>No</VATISAGNSTCANCSALES>
       <VATISPURCEXEMPTED>No</VATISPURCEXEMPTED>
       <ISVATRESTAXINVOICE>No</ISVATRESTAXINVOICE>
       <VATISASSESABLECALCVCH>No</VATISASSESABLECALCVCH>
       <ISVATDUTYPAID>Yes</ISVATDUTYPAID>
       <ISDELIVERYSAMEASCONSIGNEE>No</ISDELIVERYSAMEASCONSIGNEE>
       <ISDISPATCHSAMEASCONSIGNOR>No</ISDISPATCHSAMEASCONSIGNOR>
       <ISDELETEDVCHRETAINED>No</ISDELETEDVCHRETAINED>
       <CHANGEVCHMODE>No</CHANGEVCHMODE>
       <RESETIRNQRCODE>No</RESETIRNQRCODE>
       <ALTERID> 189660</ALTERID>
       <MASTERID> 59532</MASTERID>
       <VOUCHERKEY>190206921670808</VOUCHERKEY>
       <EWAYBILLDETAILS.LIST>      </EWAYBILLDETAILS.LIST>
       <EXCLUDEDTAXATIONS.LIST>      </EXCLUDEDTAXATIONS.LIST>
       <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>      </OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
       <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>      </ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
       <AUDITENTRIES.LIST>      </AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
       <DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>      </DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
       <ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
        <BASICUSERDESCRIPTION.LIST TYPE="String">
         <BASICUSERDESCRIPTION>Men Cream Trousers</BASICUSERDESCRIPTION>
        </BASICUSERDESCRIPTION.LIST>
        <STOCKITEMNAME>xyz230_09_LC_28</STOCKITEMNAME>
        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
        <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
        <ISAUTONEGATE>No</ISAUTONEGATE>
        <ISCUSTOMSCLEARANCE>No</ISCUSTOMSCLEARANCE>
        <ISTRACKCOMPONENT>No</ISTRACKCOMPONENT>
        <ISTRACKPRODUCTION>No</ISTRACKPRODUCTION>
        <ISPRIMARYITEM>No</ISPRIMARYITEM>
        <ISSCRAP>No</ISSCRAP>
        <RATE>465.71/PC</RATE>
        <AMOUNT>465.71</AMOUNT>
        <ACTUALQTY>1 PC</ACTUALQTY>
        <BILLEDQTY>1 PC</BILLEDQTY>
        <BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <GODOWNNAME>Main Location</GODOWNNAME>
         <BATCHNAME>Primary Batch</BATCHNAME>
         <INDENTNO/>
         <ORDERNO/>
         <TRACKINGNUMBER/>
         <DYNAMICCSTISCLEARED>No</DYNAMICCSTISCLEARED>
         <AMOUNT>465.71</AMOUNT>
         <ACTUALQTY>1 PC</ACTUALQTY>
         <BILLEDQTY>1 PC</BILLEDQTY>
         <ADDITIONALDETAILS.LIST>        </ADDITIONALDETAILS.LIST>
         <VOUCHERCOMPONENTLIST.LIST>        </VOUCHERCOMPONENTLIST.LIST>
        </BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
          <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
         </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
         <LEDGERNAME>Interstate Sales 5%</LEDGERNAME>
         <GSTCLASS/>
         <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
         <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
         <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
         <ISPARTYLEDGER>No</ISPARTYLEDGER>
         <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
         <ISCAPVATTAXALTERED>No</ISCAPVATTAXALTERED>
         <ISCAPVATNOTCLAIMED>No</ISCAPVATNOTCLAIMED>
         <AMOUNT>23.29</AMOUNT>
         <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>        </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
         <BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>        </BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>        </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>        </INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
         <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>        </OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
         <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>        </ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
         <AUDITENTRIES.LIST>        </AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
         <INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>        </INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>
         <DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>        </DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
         <EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>        </EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
         <RATEDETAILS.LIST>        </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
         <SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>        </SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>
         <STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>        </STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>
         <EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>        </EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>        </TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>        </TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>        </TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>        </VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>
         <COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST>        </COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>        </REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>
         <INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>        </INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>
         <VATITCDETAILS.LIST>        </VATITCDETAILS.LIST>
         <ADVANCETAXDETAILS.LIST>        </ADVANCETAXDETAILS.LIST>
        </ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
        <SUPPLEMENTARYDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </SUPPLEMENTARYDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
        <TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>       </REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>
        <EXCISEALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </EXCISEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <EXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </EXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
       </ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
       <SUPPLEMENTARYDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>      </SUPPLEMENTARYDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
       <EWAYBILLERRORLIST.LIST>      </EWAYBILLERRORLIST.LIST>
       <IRNERRORLIST.LIST>      </IRNERRORLIST.LIST>
       <INVOICEDELNOTES.LIST>      </INVOICEDELNOTES.LIST>
       <INVOICEORDERLIST.LIST>      </INVOICEORDERLIST.LIST>
       <INVOICEINDENTLIST.LIST>      </INVOICEINDENTLIST.LIST>
       <ATTENDANCEENTRIES.LIST>      </ATTENDANCEENTRIES.LIST>
       <ORIGINVOICEDETAILS.LIST>      </ORIGINVOICEDETAILS.LIST>
       <INVOICEEXPORTLIST.LIST>      </INVOICEEXPORTLIST.LIST>
       <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
        <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
         <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
        </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
        <LEDGERNAME>abc Internet Pvt. Ltd</LEDGERNAME>
        <GSTCLASS/>
        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
        <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
        <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
        <ISPARTYLEDGER>Yes</ISPARTYLEDGER>
        <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
        <ISCAPVATTAXALTERED>No</ISCAPVATTAXALTERED>
        <ISCAPVATNOTCLAIMED>No</ISCAPVATNOTCLAIMED>
        <AMOUNT>-489.0</AMOUNT>
        <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
        <BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
         <NAME>12133584915561400</NAME>
         <BILLTYPE>Agst Ref</BILLTYPE>
         <TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>No</TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>
         <AMOUNT>-489.0</AMOUNT>
         <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>        </INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
         <STBILLCATEGORIES.LIST>        </STBILLCATEGORIES.LIST>
        </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>       </INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
        <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
        <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
        <AUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
        <INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>       </INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>
        <DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
        <EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
        <RATEDETAILS.LIST>       </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
        <SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>       </SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>
        <STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>       </STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>
        <EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>       </VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>
        <COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>       </REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>
        <INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>       </INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>
        <VATITCDETAILS.LIST>       </VATITCDETAILS.LIST>
        <ADVANCETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </ADVANCETAXDETAILS.LIST>
       </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
       <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
        <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
         <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
        </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
        <LEDGERNAME>Output IGST 5%</LEDGERNAME>
        <GSTCLASS/>
        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
        <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
        <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
        <ISPARTYLEDGER>No</ISPARTYLEDGER>
        <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
        <ISCAPVATTAXALTERED>No</ISCAPVATTAXALTERED>
        <ISCAPVATNOTCLAIMED>No</ISCAPVATNOTCLAIMED>
        <AMOUNT>23.29</AMOUNT>
        <VATEXPAMOUNT>23.29</VATEXPAMOUNT>
        <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
        <BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>       </INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
        <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
        <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
        <AUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
        <INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>       </INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>
        <DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
        <EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
        <RATEDETAILS.LIST>       </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
        <SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>       </SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>
        <STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>       </STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>
        <EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>       </VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>
        <COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </COSTTRACKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>       </REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>
        <INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>       </INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>
        <VATITCDETAILS.LIST>       </VATITCDETAILS.LIST>
        <ADVANCETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </ADVANCETAXDETAILS.LIST>
       </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
       <PAYROLLMODEOFPAYMENT.LIST>      </PAYROLLMODEOFPAYMENT.LIST>
       <ATTDRECORDS.LIST>      </ATTDRECORDS.LIST>
       <GSTEWAYCONSIGNORADDRESS.LIST>      </GSTEWAYCONSIGNORADDRESS.LIST>
       <GSTEWAYCONSIGNEEADDRESS.LIST>      </GSTEWAYCONSIGNEEADDRESS.LIST>
       <TEMPGSTRATEDETAILS.LIST>      </TEMPGSTRATEDETAILS.LIST>
       <UDF:_UDF_788536871.LIST DESC="" ISLIST="YES" TYPE="String" INDEX="7718">
        <UDF:_UDF_788536871 DESC="">64UVR2200000001</UDF:_UDF_788536871>
       </UDF:_UDF_788536871.LIST>
       <UDF:_UDF_788569522.LIST DESC="" ISLIST="YES" TYPE="String" INDEX="40369">
        <UDF:_UDF_788569522 DESC="">208995059264UVR220000000130-May-211-Apr-21IMP-11:00-b719dd2a-03bb-41c2-a639-69ab4238f0a8</UDF:_UDF_788569522>
       </UDF:_UDF_788569522.LIST>
      </VOUCHER>
     </TALLYMESSAGE>
     <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
      <COMPANY>
       <REMOTECMPINFO.LIST MERGE="Yes">
        <NAME>94eebd66-d8bc-42a4-a58e-96d09c3b0702</NAME>
        <REMOTECMPNAME>xyz abc</REMOTECMPNAME>
        <REMOTECMPSTATE>Rajasthan</REMOTECMPSTATE>
       </REMOTECMPINFO.LIST>
      </COMPANY>
     </TALLYMESSAGE>
     <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
      <COMPANY>
       <REMOTECMPINFO.LIST MERGE="Yes">
        <NAME>94eebd66-d8bc-42a4-a58e-96d09c3b0702</NAME>
        <REMOTECMPNAME>xyz</REMOTECMPNAME>
        <REMOTECMPSTATE>abc</REMOTECMPSTATE>
       </REMOTECMPINFO.LIST>
      </COMPANY>
     </TALLYMESSAGE>
    </REQUESTDATA>
   </IMPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
 </ENVELOPE>
```

I have got following error

Voucher totals do not match! Dr: 489.00 Dr Cr: 46.58 Cr Diff: 442.42 Dr

Please guys help me to remove this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some rules you need to follow While posting Voucher among them

- Voucher Totals should be zero means If you Sum all debit amount and credit amount result should be zero

the reason your totals are not matching is your sales amount is wrong

As per inventory your sales amount is **465.71** but you mentioned Interstate Sales 5% as **23.39** which is wrong
If change that error will go

```
...........
  <ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
        <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
            <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
        </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
        <LEDGERNAME>Interstate Sales 5%</LEDGERNAME>
        <GSTCLASS />
        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
        <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
        <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
        <ISPARTYLEDGER>No</ISPARTYLEDGER>
        <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
        <ISCAPVATTAXALTERED>No</ISCAPVATTAXALTERED>
        <ISCAPVATNOTCLAIMED>No</ISCAPVATNOTCLAIMED>
        <AMOUNT>465.71</AMOUNT>
 ........
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an answer, not exactly for the issue reported but in general

Tally accepts upto two digits only, so while importing, make sure that the data is rounded to two decimal digits and all the values match up accordingly otherwise similar error will come with difference value of 0.00 as tally shows upto two digits only, but the difference might be beyond two digits. use rounding off routines available in the language you are coding to avoid this issue.